# Неудачно передается 2ой параметр в jquery

Tags: jquery, php, javascript

Параметры с формы передаются с начало в пхп а потом в jquery. Все работает как часы кроме 2ого параметра, который отвечает за максимальную стоимость. И получается, что он получает все элементы от заданный стоимости и до самого дорогого. Вот код и скриншот. На кодировку не смотрите)

```
<?
$x= $_GET['params'];
$min = $x[minprice];
$max = $x[maxprice];

$min=(string)$min;
$max=(string)$max;

$url = 'http://www.xxx.ru/doors/filters.php?params%5Bminprice%5D='.$min.'&params%5Bmaxprice%5D=440&filters=1';
$htm = file_get_contents($url);
print' <script type="text/javascript">
     $("#main-content").empty().load("getxxx.php?url=http://www.xxx.ru/doors/filters.php?params%5Bminprice%5D='.$min.'&params%5Bmaxprice%5D=440&filters=1 .style02",function(){$(".navipath").remove() ; $(".impLinks").remove()});
    </script>)'
?>
```

код getxxx.php

```
<?php

$url = $_GET['url'];



$htm = file_get_contents($url);


//iconv_set_encoding("internal_encoding", "windows-1251");
//iconv_set_encoding("output_encoding", "UTF-8");
//ob_start($htm); // старт буферизации вывода
echo iconv("windows-1251","utf-8",$htm)
?>
```

[image]

Comment: У вас все файлы должны быть в "UTF-8 без BOM", а сравнение текстовых полей таблицы - "utf8_general_ci". Если всё будет так, то проблемы с кодировкой исчезнут, т.к. ajax нормально работает именно с UTF-8

Comment: да с кодировкой все в порядке. она толко почему то из под убунту такая. В виндовс все норм

Comment: @Not even close, если с кодировкой всё нормально, тогда зачем вы преобразовываете строку из cp1251 в UTF-8?

Comment: Потому что сайт с которого скачивается страница в cp1251

Comment: @Not even close, допустим. Но так или иначе, если у вас с кодировкой всё гуд, то преобразование даст положительный результат. Попробуйте [mb_convert_encoding][1]:

    exit( mb_convert_encoding($htm, 'utf-8', 'cp1251') );

   [1]:http://ua2.php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-convert-encoding.php

Comment: Попробовал) ничего не изменилось

Comment: @Not even close, что я могу сазать?... Сейчас даже попробовал найти сайт с такой кодировкой (*оказывается, что они еще существуют*), проверил у себя - всё идельно. Давайте, ради интереса, ссылку на ваш ресурс, попробую потестить на нём.


P.S. Честно говоря, я в вашем коде вообще мало чего понимаю. Почему-то вы получаете контент и до ajax-запроса, а потом и им ковыряете, да и сам js-код появляется, как "здрасьте", а не по-человечески прописан в JS-файле. В общем, жарко на улице, мозг кипит.

Comment: Хах, Странно имено эта страница изначально в utf8 И ее не надо переводить. хотя все отсальные в Cp1251. Проблема с кодировкой изчесзла а вот 2ой параметр все так же не передается )